# Simple noob I/O question (C++)

Tags: c++, input, cout, cin

sorry for the noob question, but I'm new to C++.

I need to read some information, line-by-line, from a file, and perform some calculations, and output into another file. For example, we read a unique ID for each line, a name, and 2 numbers. The last 2 numbers are multiplied, and in the output file, the ID, name and product are printed line by line:

**input.txt:**

```
2431 John Doe 2000 5
9856 Jane Doe 1800 2 
4029 Jack Siu 3000 10
```

**output.txt:**

```
  ID     Name Total
2431 John Doe 10000
9856 Jane Doe 3600
4029 Jack Siu 30000
```

My code is similar to this, but only the first line appears in the output file. If I press `Enter` repeatedly, the other lines appear in the output file:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream cin("input.txt");
ofstream cout("output.txt");

int main () {

    int ID, I, J;
    string First, Last;
    char c;

    cout << "ID\tName\t\Total\n";

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        cin >> ID >> First >> Last >> I >> J;
        cout << ID << " " << First << " " << Last << " " I * J << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That's my only problem, that the values don't appear in the output file, unless I press `Enter` repeatedly, then close the program. Can anyone suggest a fix for my code above, to have it do the task without keyboard input? Thanks!

Comment: Change the cin/cout to something else. It is very confusing to read and might cause problems.

Comment: Just a matter of convention, `cin` and `cout` are defined in the header `<iostream>` to refer to `stdin` and `stdout`.  If you want to use files for input and output, use the console's redirection capabilities:  `app < input.txt > output.txt`.  Now your app can use different input and output files without being recompiled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
while (!cin.eof()) {
```

Comment: wrong again, use `while( cin >> someChar )`. It's better as it checks for every error flag. And please don't reuse `std::cin`, create your own `std::istream`

Comment: The problem with istream::eof is that it's not forward-looking. It merely tells you that the last read succeeded.

Answer (score 7):

```
using namespace std;

ifstream cin("input.txt");
ofstream cout("output.txt");
```

You've hidden the real std::cin and std::cout...and will later read from them.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

But here you use the real std::cin to check for EOF.

Answer (score 6):

The `getchar()` call reads waits for you to type a character (and press Enter) since it reads from stdin (standard input). Try changing the loop condition to stop reading when `cin` reaches end of file.

*EDIT*
You should also use different names for input and output streams -- there are already `cin` and `cout` in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you used getchar() in your while loop condition. Not sure what you were trying to do, but getchar() reads a char from stdin. What you should have done, is check if cin failed or encountered EOF.

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for the answer I though I better check and make sure it worked.  I got some build errors and got a little carried away from there.

Hope this helps!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    ifstream indata("input.txt");
    if(!indata)
    { // file couldn't be opened
        cerr << "Error: input.txt could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ofstream output("output.txt");
    if(!output)
    { // file couldn't be opened
        cerr << "Error: output.txt could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int ID, I, J;
    char First[10], Last[10];

    output << "ID\tName\tTotal\n";
    while (!indata.eof()) 
    {
        indata >> ID >> First >> Last >> I >> J;
        output << ID << " " << First << " " << Last << " " << I * J << endl;
    }

    indata.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```